# How can i print a success message for insert,update or delete?

Tags: php

I have a **select page** which displays all records from a table.For each record there is a corresponding link for editing / deleting a record.In this page,I have also given a link which opens up another page for inserting records.

When I click on the delete link for a particular record , a **delete.php** is executed which deletes the record and redirects the user to the **select** page

Now , I want to display a success message(delete) in the **select page** (just below the records which are displayed).How can I position the success message just below the records that are displayed ?

Should i use **mysqli_affected_rows** and pass this value to the **select** page .How do i pass this value?

My delete.php file looks something like this :

```
include "connection.php";
$sql = "DELETE FROM `student`  
WHERE `id` = '$_GET[del_id]'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Delete Error");
Header("Location: select.php");
```

Comment: remove the header and and add echo and all in an `if{}/else{}`. Surely you could have done that without our help

Comment: Success message based on deleted record or simply one simple message "record deleted"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would use sessions. These allow you to store data that you can retrieve when the same user loads another page. The example below uses this approach

**delete.php**

```
<?php
//session must be started before anything is echoed to the browser
if(session_status()===PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
...
mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Delete Error");
$_SESSION['message'] = "Record #$_GET[del_id] was successfully deleted"; 
Header("Location: select.php");
```

Then on any page, you can check whether there is a message to display. If so, retrieve it and clear the message store (so user doesn't see the same message every time she opens a new page).

**select.php**

```
<?php
//session must be started before anything is echoed to the browser
if(session_status()===PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
...
//capture the message if it exists, or set $msg to null
if(!empty($_SESSION['message'])){
    $msg = $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']); //delete the message
}else{$msg = null;}
```

Now you can display `$msg` anywhere you want in the HTML if it is not null.

**In response to your comments:**  You asked why sessions must be started before all output:

Any setting that affects HTTP response headers must come before output goes to the browser because in the HTTP protocol, headers come before content.  Sessions rely on headers by default (the `Cookie` header to be exact). [From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: @SabyasachiGupta You're welcome. Remember to select and upvote this answer if you choose to use it

Comment: Just wanted to clarify a doubt : You have mentioned in your code that "session must be started before anything is echoed to the browser" . Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: @SabyasachiGupta I added a bit to my answer to address your question